# How to change where a CSS transition starts from?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

Suppose I have a `<div>` which I would like to expand from a small size to a bigger size (See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZUeu/38/)).

By default, a width and height CSS3 transition on a `<div>` will start from the top left and progress to the bottom right. However, I want the `<div>` to expand from the top right corner to the bottom left.

**Here is my question: Is there any way I could make the `<div>` undergo a width and height transition from the top right corner to the bottom left?**

Here's an image to clarify my question. Basically, I would like my `<div>` to expand like the box on the right, not like the default way, shown by the box on the left.
[image: Description of Problem: I would like my <code><div></code> to expand from the top right to the bottom left, as shown below, rather than from the top left to the bottom right.]

**Here's another image:**
[image]

Comment: Rather than floating the element to the left, if you float the div to the right, the transition will occur as desired.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not in a position to float right; I need to have a grid of these tiles, and they need to be align properly together.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to reach. I can imagine that dark grey boxes in your fiddle expands in any direction :) Can you provide more detailed before/after transition description or image?

Comment: Umm...not exactly sure how to show it much clearer. But basically, I want the transition to start from a different corner of the div, not the default corner. If you look closely in the fiddle, both of the divs expand from left to right and top to bottom. I would like to make them expand right to left instead.

Comment: So you want top and right sides to stay where they are but left and bottom sides expand? For example, when second square hovered should it overlap first one and not to push text to the right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm being clear. Basically, I want this kind of effect: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZUeu/19/, except the divs should move around with the transition, instead of just staying put.

Comment: And how should look a final result of hovering second div? Other divs should move?

Comment: I'm sorry for all that questions but it is still not clear. How exactly should other divs move? Should first or third div move (on second div hover)? Should any div go down somewhere? It will be perfect if you can make an image where should be divs after second box hover.

Comment: To me it would be helpful to have small graphical sketch. What should it look like before and after a hover. As I imagine it does not make a difference if a div is transformed from left or from right, if all surrounding divs are moved alongside

Comment: I don't think you can accomplish what you are looking for without pushing the other blocks off the screen to the left or floating the elements right.  You are actually getting the result you're looking for in your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/7ZUeu/1/) when you hover over the first and then go to the second.  This is because the available space permits it.  Otherwise it *must* grow from the top-left because there's nowhere else for it to go.

Comment: @antejan, the questions are totally fine; you can't solve the problem without knowing what the problem is. :)
I added another image in the question. Hopefully that clears it up.

Comment: It is much clearer with new image, thank you! I see problem when top side of 2 goes below top side of 1 and 3 - this is impossible with floats by spec and can be done only with some workaround. Need to experiment.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that float issue. That's why I'm gonna change the requirements for the bounty, since floating probably won't work as well here.

Comment: Do you need an universal solution (which will be hard I think) or you have specific task and we can make solution simpler?

Comment: Umm...unfortunately, this is pretty much the specific task as such. I am make a grid of tiles in which one column of tiles will expand from top left to bottom right, and the other column will expand from top right to bottom left.

Comment: So far, ScottS is closest to what I'm looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZUeu/44/. (This answer works. I just want to see if there's a better way to do this.)

Comment: Bounty awarded to ScottS. But thank you all for helpful and constructive answers! +1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you want to have things "shift", then you don't really see the fact that it is growing from the right to the left, but [I think this achieves what you are desiring](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZUeu/30/) (it tweaks some other margins, and adds a relative shift):

```css
div {
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-color:rgba(25,25,25,0.7);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
div:hover {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:10px 115px 0px -105px;
    right: -110px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Note, simply because of the nature of floats and having the items shift, you will get some bizarre behavior with many elements. [Play around with this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZUeu/31/) when it is downsized so there are at least two rows of divs.

**Explanation of Margins**

The `115px` right margin pushes the following element over (the "shift" you wanted) making space for the element to expand. It is the width of the element, plus the `5px` margins on the elements, plus the fact that the larger size element is increasing its margin to `10px`. It is *into* this space that the `right` shift occurs. The direction of the expansion itself happens through the `-105px`, which is what causes the element to expand left (as you originally wanted).

UPDATE to your newer pictures: [Take a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZUeu/61/). There are still some small bugs, but functions nicely based on a set of three div's (there is an extra non-semantic `span` to make my functionality work).

Comment: I like the idea of using a relative shift, but unfortunately, this doesn't have the top right to bottom left transition I'm looking for. Nevertheless, this is leaning me towards a closer answer; +1.

Comment: @Bagavatu: I don't think your TR/BL transition is _visually_ possible if you are wanting to shift elements for two reasons: 1) mine actually [IS doing that](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZUeu/37/), but it doesn't _look_ like it because as it transitions TR/BL it is also moving `right` (that fiddle removed the `right` shift). Which leads to 2) it has to "shift" elements right because it cannot affect elements to its left (with `float: left`) using pure css. Now if you can do `float: right` [you can get the effect with a TR/BL look](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZUeu/44/).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you! This seems to be the best answer so far though! I'll accept + award bounty soon if a better answer doesn't come up.

Comment: @Bagavatu: If you are just needing three elements, then I think I can get some interesting functionality _similar_ (though not quite the same) as what you image above. See my update answer.

Comment: That looks awesome! Just one question: I didn't exactly understand how you set the margins of `margin:10px 115px 0px -105px;`. Could you please explain that to me?

Comment: @Bagavatu: I added an explanation to the answer. I hope that helps. I also plan to try and refine the code some when I have time, as there are some bugs that I want to minimize (example, hover on "2" and then move straight to "1").

Comment: Thank you ScottS! +50 Bounty.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your `div:hover` margins to something like `margin:10px 10px 0px -100px;` and get the desired effect. However, you will need to adjust your margins on both the div and the hover (if you can't use float:right). http://jsfiddle.net/7ZUeu/14/

Comment: Ah, but the issue is that now the divs don't move dynamically. The negative margins simply overlay the divs.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I am not sure of a pure css transition way to do that without `float:right`.

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for more details requested in comments under question.

For now I understand task like this http://jsfiddle.net/7ZUeu/34/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  float:left;
}

.box {
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  float:right;
  background:url(http://placekitten.com/200/200/) no-repeat 100% 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
      -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
       -o-transition: all .5s ease;
          transition: all .5s ease;
}
.box:hover {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is incomplete, but perhaps if you wrap them in another fixed div. Again, this is sort of ugly, but maybe it's in the right direction. (Borrowing ScottS's fiddle).

```
div.one,.two,.three {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  margin:3px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-color:rgba(25,25,25,0.7);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

div.one:hover,div.two:hover {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:3px 113px 0px -100px;
  right: -110px;
  float:right;
}

div.three:hover {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:3px 113px 0px -100px;
  right: -110px;
}

div.fixed {
  width: 330px;
  height: 220px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}
```

I've also split up the divs, because it seems like you can only corral two of them in a given direction...

http://jsfiddle.net/YAGmC/1/

Comment: This solution is close, but the issue is that it flickers around a lot. I'm pretty sure that's because of the float. Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.right{
width:100px; 
height:100px; 
float:right;
background-color:#000000;
}

.right:hover{
margin-left:-300px;
width:300px;
transition:0.3s
}
```